# how to allow access to web page only specific mobile app?

Tags: android, web, referrer

I create web pages for inserting webview in android app.

so I want to allow access to web pages ONLY app?

how to allow access to web page only specific mobile app?

referrer check using app url?

Comment: Why? Does it need to be secure? Are you afraid of hackers? If you are afraid of hackers, note that referrers can easily be spoofed. But if you're not really afraid of people/hackers having access to those pages, just make your urls obscure, and tell robots.txt/sitemap.xml not to index the underlying domain and underlying folder of those urls. At least, that will keep out the main search engines, it just won't keep out the hackers.

Comment: If you really want to do so, you can try user agent(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent).

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own user-agent string

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)

Something like this

```
yourWebView.getWebSettings().setUserAgentString("Cool String to be parsed");
```

Then in your HTML you can catch this UserAgent string. In JavaScript is

```
navigator.userAgent
```

If you want other languages to manage it you can do it in PHP or Python to make it server-side.

But if you want true security... there is no a safe way. A kid can also emulates your webview's behaviour.